# Pass functor to constructor

Tags: c++, functor

I have a class that basically needs to store a functor given in the constructor, similar to this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
   private:
     T func;
   public:
     Foo(T f) : func(f) { }
}
```

However, to create a new instance of the Foo class, the I can't seem to do this:

```
Foo foo(std::less<int>());
```

because T is a class template parameter. I have to use this clunky syntax instead:

```
Foo<std::less<int>> foo(std::less<int>());
```

Is there a better way to do this, without writing the type of the functor twice?

Comment: You can provide a `make_foo(std::less<int>())` interface.

Comment: @chris +1. ive seen some of your comments today; i just like the way you think. but you could get even further with the crazy shenanigans like Casey showed ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo` is not a class, it is a class template. You have to instantiate it with a template argument in order to create a type.

Concerning your example, you could add a default constructor for functors that are default constructible, like `std::less` et al.

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
   private:
     T func;
   public:
     Foo() = default; // C++03 would require Foo() {}
     Foo(T f) : func(f) { }
};
```

then

```
Foo<std::less<int>> foo;
```

Alternatively, you can provide a function template that takes a functor and returns a `Foo<F>` object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function to deduce the functor type and return the correct `Foo` flavor:

```
template <typename T>
Foo<T> make_foo(T t) { return Foo<T>(t); }
```

but this solution basically needs `auto` from C++11 to store the return value:

```
auto f = make_foo(std::less<int>());
```